# DLL not found when importing a manually-built cv2 with Gstreamer plugin to the python environment

Tags: opencv, dll, build, gstreamer

The main issue I’m facing is that when I try to import cv2 that I manually built to the python environment, I received an error saying that the DLL load failed. Allow me to tell you the steps I did prior to this point.

I wanted to use Gstreamer with OpenCV, but since OpenCV doesn’t come native with Gstreamer, I had to build it manually from source.

Here’s my current setup:

- Windows 10 22H2
- Python 3.12
- Gstreamer 1.24.0 MinGWx64
- Cmake GUI 3.29.0
- OpenCV 4.9.0 downloaded from the official site
- Visual Studio Community 2022 (17.9.4)

I had [this guide](https://galaktyk.medium.com/how-to-build-opencv-with-gstreamer-b11668fa09c) as reference for my installation.

After I browsed for the source file and press configure, the CMake GUI did some process and [this is what it looked like after the process was done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ0o7.png)

Notice that the values of some names in the Gstreamer section seems to be missing. Also in the Cmake log (lower part), Gstreamer is marked as NO.

I then added `GSTREAMER_DIR` as an entry via the "Add entry" button, pointing to my Gstreamer installation folder. After re-configuring, all of the values are now filled as like this, and Gstreamer is now marked as YES (1.24.0). [After this step, the GUI looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EsuM.png)

Next, I proceed to Generate, open the project in Visual Studio, then build the source as shown in the guide. The final build had 1 failed component (not sure if it's right to call it a component, but it showed something like the snippet below. It also had a few [error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYjIw.png))

```
========== Build: 94 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 10:44 PM and took 08:27.743 minutes ==========
```

Though when I checked inside the `build\lib\python3\Release` folder, there was a `.pyd` file in it (cv2.cp312-win_amd64.pyd). I then copied this to my `site-packages` folder in my python installation folder and tried to import it. Sadly, the import didn't work, and it showed this error, saying that DLL load failed. Runtime was in CMD, by the way.

```
Python 3.12.2 (tags/v3.12.2:6abddd9, Feb  6 2024, 21:26:36) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\NICE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\NICE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\NICE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

I'm really stumped as to what to do next. Can you point me to the right direction?

Since the error showed that it couldn't load DLL (God knows which one), I tried to use process monitoring to check what DLLs are missing. Upon brief inspection, most DLLs have the result of `NAME NOT FOUND`, but a few lines down, that corresponding DLL is loaded from another directory and the result is `SUCCESS`, so I'm assuming the DLL was found at another location, and has been loaded successfully.

However, there is one DLL file that seems to never get the `SUCCESS` result, and it is the `opencv_videoio.dll`. I noticed that the project name shown in my Visual Studio error list is also similar to this name, so maybe there's some correlation between them? If it helps, I saved the process monitor log when I tried to import cv2 to python and uploaded to my Google Drive.

What's weird is that `opencv_videoio.dll` is inside the build folder. I even tried to manually include the build folder using this code

```
import os
os.add_dll_directory(path\to\my\build\folder)
```

Also, here are some minor things I did which may be relevant:

1. When I didn't manually add the missing values and built it with Gstreamer marked as NO, the build was successful and I could import it properly in python by copying the .pyd file to my site-lib directory. So I'm thinking if something is wrong with my Gstreamer installation or something? (I tried installing the MSVC version as well, and it also didn't build properly. I might say it built worse, failing to build around 40 components instead of just 1)
2. I also tried installing NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit as a last ditch attempt. I made sure to reset the CMake cache, and repeat the process from scratch, but the error seems to be the same. Similar to the page, I also tried including the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit installation folder to the dll directory with this code, but the error is still not fixed.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.4\bin")
<AddedDllDirectory('C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.4\\bin')>
```